# Silverlight & SQL Server

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can someone provide a very simple example of how to load a datagrid with data from SQL Server, in a Silverlight application?

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is also a nice and detailed article:

[Silverlight 3: Displaying SQL Server Data](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Silverlight3_SQL_WCF.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Silverlight learning site](http://www.silverlight.net). It has **tons** of contents - including many community samples.

This one might be for you: [Lightweight DataList](http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/lightweight-datalist--36722/).

Or check out the vast [collection of Silverlight How-To videos](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/) - this one might be yours: [Getting started with the DataGrid](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/getting-started-with-the-datagrid/)

If not: browse around, I'm sure there's tons of good stuff and samples there!